# python List Duplicates Identify and assign a value

Tags: list, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a list like L=[A,B,B,C,C,C]
I need the resultant list to be L=[A,B-1,B-2,C-1,C-2,C-3] 
i.e all the duplicates need to have a running number while keeping the order same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby` to find "runs" of elements and build a new list from there:

```
import itertools

L = [A,B,B,C,C,C]
answer = []
for _k, group in itertools.groupby(L):
    group = list(group)
    if len(group) == 1:
        answer.extend(group)
        continue
    answer.extend(("{}-{}".format(e,i) for i,e in enumerate(group, 1)))
```